# How can change the base url of search auto complete, buy button in magento 1.7

Tags: search, autocomplete, magento-1.7

This is below code is currently I have, i want to change it to http://localhost/magento15/ where i need to change.?

```html
<button type="button" class="button" style="float: right;
margin-top: -38px;
margin-right: 35px;" id="pr_2" onclick="setLocation('http://localhost/magento14/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2tlcHJhbnByb2plY3RzLmNvbS9raS9pbmRleC5waHAv/product/2/qty/1/')">
  <span>Buy</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the URL's for BUY button only for search results page. If you change it will reflect the same for all the buy buttons of total website.